# How to assign arrayList values into related labels in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist

This is a sign-up form with 3 textboxes and one dateTimePicker. There also have to be 4 buttons(add, show, prev and next) - when you click add button, it's supposed to store data typed by an each user and show button must print out information related to each one to the labels, then I should be able to walk through on eveyone's data when I click on prev and next buttons.

Simple as it sounds but I don't know how to assign values from textboxes into labels using ArrayList collections. How  to do that?

```
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    int ind = 0;
    private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        list.Add(textBox1.Text);
        list.Add(textBox2.Text);
        list.Add(textBox3.Text);
        list.Add(dateTimePicker1.Text);


        textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       {
            label5.Text = 
            label6.Text = 
            label7.Text = 
            label8.Text =
```

Comment: you get access to the element in the list like this `list[0]`, `list[1]`, `list[2]` but it would retrieve `Object` so you need to cast it as string. Try `label5.Text = list[0].ToString();` and let me know if worked. I haven't used ArrayList for many years. Currently we use `List<string>` as you don't need to cast elements. Also you need to validate the list contains elements before retrieving them. Check out Count property. `if(list.Count>0) { //set values to labels  };`

Comment: List[0], List[1], if I assign them  to labels with exact index numbers It'll always replace a previous user's information written in textbox with new one's when I click add button so I wont't be able to store all the datas typed by the various users properly. Is there anything that keeps them all in memory without removing previous one's?

Comment: Then create a class for storing current input (including all fields) and save this object as one element in the list.

Comment: OMG, sorry for my hurriedness, it worked pretty well without removing any previous list values :))